# Error in Design studio while importing t24 versions

Tags: jbase

I am trying to import Temenos T24 versions from DataBase to Design Studio. I can easily import all kinds of data using import option in DS, except T24 Versions which are not importing. And while importing I got error message like "Unable to import, Unordered add not supported". Any idea regarding the import versions in data.eson format?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import T24 Versions using option "Import T24 Screens", and you need to import the versions, i.e. screens under "xxxxx-models" project. Best to create a separate folder, like "L3" under your "-models" project.

Same goes for Enquiries, Menus, Composite Screens and Tabbed Screens.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible import versions in data.eson format. All you need is to use "Bulk import T24 objects". Then you need to point to the .csv file with record list. Records needs to be provided in the following way:

```
APPLICATION,RECORD.ID
```

Since versions contains coma in the id, it has to be in double quotas. I.e.:

```
ENQUIRY,MY.ENQUIRY
VERSION,"CUSTOMER,INPUT"
```

Then you need to tick "Import models as data ESON only".